# Beautiful Soup using html.parser having troubles decoding quotation marks

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a simple program to grab the text of an article from Fox News, but for some reason I am having troubles getting the quotation marks to be decoded correctly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

r = urllib.urlopen('http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2016/10/14/emails-reveal-clinton-teams-early-plan-for-handling-bill-sex-scandals.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='article-text'):
    print item.get_text().encode('UTF-8')
```

This grabs the text I am looking for, but for almost all quotation marks in the article they are printed like this: Bill Clintonâ€™s.  I have tried specifically defining the decoding to be in utf-8 and have looked at the page to see what encoding it declares and it is utf-8 as well so I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Where are you running this from?

Comment: I'm just running this on my laptop, using Eclipse Mars with pydev.

Comment: I mean what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm running Windows 10, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this does not solve why Beautiful Soup was having issues decoding the text, but I have found two roundabout ways to solve the issue.  One is to declare an encoding at the top of the script:

```
      # This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
```

The other is to decode and remove all Unicode characters, then encode again with ascii.

```
print(temp.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore'))
```